# How to avoid this OperationError in Django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to implement a Many to One relationship in Django.

This is my code:

**models.py**

```
class Entry(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    class Meta:

        ordering = ['-date']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Entradas'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('blog_entries', None, {'slug': self.slug})

class Comment(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry, related_name='comments')
    #add image field
    username = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog.models import Entry, Comment

class AdminEntry(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'date', 'content','slug')
    #prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("titulo",)}
    list_filter = ('title', 'date')
    ordering = ('-date',)
    search_fields = ('title',)

admin.site.register(Entry, AdminEntry)

class AdminComment(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display= ('username','content')

admin.site.register(Comment, AdminComment)
```

Then I do:

**python manage.py syncdb**

**python manage.py runserver**

When I go to the Comment section of the admin, I get this:

```
OperationalError at /admin/blog/comment/
no such column: blog_comment.content
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/blog/comment/
Django Version: 1.6.1
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such column: blog_comment.content
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 450
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/boel/Dropbox/boeldev',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
Server time:    Thu, 6 Feb 2014 22:39:05 +0000
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

syncdb doesn't add columns on existing tables. Either drop your table and run it again, or use South to create migrations.